# Dynamics CRM : Subgrid not showing field values

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Using : Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 On Premise

I am working on Quote customization form. Here we have Products Subgrid by default added.

[image]

Also, I have added these last two custom fields in this grid to show.

[image]

If you notice here on the grid, Product Name is not displaying.

When I select that particular Line Item, I see product name on "Quote Product" entity form as below.

[image]

Below is the screen of my Subgrid set up.

[image]

What is missing here, so that it is not displaying Product name on the grid? Can anyone please guide me here?

Thank you,
Mittal.

Comment: If you scroll to the left, what's on the left of the Quantity column ? (looking at the 2nd screenshot of the grid, the horizontal scrollbar seems to be all the way to the right)

Comment: Yes, if you look at the second screen shot it is continuous of the first screen shot. You can see fields after Quantity in second screen shot.

Comment: I'd answer "Scroll left to see the Name" but I'm not sure I understand the issue... On a side note, you covered the Product name in the form but it's still visible in the title of the window (3rd screenshot)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here Issue is  - When you see the first Screen shot, scroll bar is all the way to the left. There is nothing beyond that. And that means, grid is not displaying the Product Name as shown on the Title of the Window(3rd screenshot)--  ;) --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since that grid is showing a particular view, is it possible that you used the wrong field? Sometimes is getting confusing between title, name or any other property.

I suggest you to open that particular view on the Quote Product list, and see if the product name appears there. If even in the list view the product name is blank you should try to modify the view until you found the field that you want.